# Create EF Foreign Key Through Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Framework isn't reacting to my data annotation changes in this particular scenario, so I want to try through Fluent API, which I never use.

I have a model "Transfer" which has three properties - its Id and "TransferredFromId" and "TransferredToId" properties, which represent Users (another EF model) involved in the transfer. Like so:

```
public class Transfer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long TransferredFromId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TransferredFromId")]
    public User TransferredFrom { get; set; }

    public long TransferredToId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TransferredToId")]
    public User TransferredTo { get; set; }
}
```

The user model currently looks like this:

```
public class User 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TransferredFrom")]
    public ICollection<Transfer> TransferredFroms { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TransferredTo")]
    public ICollection<Transfer> TransferredTos { get; set; }
}
```

Note - I think user can look like this and it would still work:

```
public class User 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

How do I achieve the exact same thing through Fluent API?

To clarify, I want to have a transfer table which has two properties, which both represent the Id from the Users table.

---

Temporary edit: Should my models look like this when I switch to Fluent API?

```
public class Transfer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long TransferredFromId { get; set; }

    public long TransferredToId { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class User 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then add this in context?

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Transfer>().HasRequired(x => x.TransferredFrom).WithMany(x => x.TransferredFroms).HasForeignKey(x => x.TransferredFromId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Transfer>().HasRequired(x => x.TransferredTo).WithMany(x => x.TransferredTos).HasForeignKey(x => x.TransferredToId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two possibilities, depending on which side you want to start on.

first, you have to override the OnModelCreating() method in your context.

your two options should look like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transfer>().HasRequired(x=>x.TransferredFrom).WithMany(x=>x.TransferredFroms).HasForeignKey(x=>x.TransferredFromId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Transfer>().HasRequired(x=>x.TransferredTo).WithMany(x=>x.TransferredTos).HasForeignKey(x=>x.TransferredToId);
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x=>x.TransferredFroms).WithRequired(x=>x.TransferredFrom).HasForeignKey(x=>x.TransferredFromId);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x=>x.TransferredTos).WithRequired(x=>x.TransferredTo).HasForeignKey(x=>x.TransferredToId);
```

each Set of these 2 lines should have the same semantics as your data annotation mapping.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I seem to understand the second option, but not the first. Where in the first does it point to the User table? Also, what should I leave in the original models? I temporarily edited my question to explain what I mean.

Comment: your navigation properties point to the user table, namely TransferredFrom, TransferredTo. you should leave these navigation properties in your model, also the inverse ones. data annotations can be deleted though. If you want to go with less navigation properties, you can skip one in the user table, if you delete both EF will get confused as to what key to use for which navigation property (even if you configure properly)